# Why is Python returning an error message to me saying something like that I used a int() wrongly

Tags: python, printing, int

This is my code:

```
def PopDensity(population, area):
    PopulationDensity = (population/area)
    return PopulationDensity
state= "Maryland"
population='6,052,000'
area="12,407"
PopDensity(int(population), int(area))
stat="The population density of %s is %s."
print(stat % (state,PopulationDensity))
```

Python keeps returning something in the above print function to me as wrong. It looks like this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:/Users/adamn/OneDrive/Desktop/.py files/Assignment5_1astrub1359960.py", line 8, in 
>           PopDensity(int(population), int(area))
>       ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6,052,000'"

Could someone plese tell me what I'm doing wrong with the print function, and suggest an improvement. I looked in another question that google reccomended me about this, but it didn't really help.

Comment: `6,052,000` is a tuple of three values, not a single number.  Try `6052000` and `12407`.

Comment: Python doesn't know how to handle commas in the string number. `replace` those, and you're good to go

Comment: @Prune It's a `str`.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: as it probably hurts to be downvoted on the first question, you can find information on how to ask good questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for bad format.

Comment: @dcg How did you put my code in the gray and yellow boxes?

Comment: @AdamStrub take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You can also use the controllers at your disposal when creating a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the number format you are passing to `int()`. You can initialize integers directly, e.g. `population = 6052000`. You are using a string instead of an integer. Correcting your code accordingly yields

```
def population_density(population, area):
    pop_density = (population/area)
    return pop_density
state= "Maryland"
population = 6052000
area = 12407
computed_density = population_density(population, area)
stat="The population density of %s is %s."
print(stat % (state,computed_density))
```